# Does highcharts have a callback function for before full chart reload (this should not include legends disable)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to empty a map only for full chart reload and not for legends change which callback function should I use?

Tried with below items:

1. load() - this function is fired once the chart is loaded completely
2. redraw() - this function is fired even for legends display

Answer (score 0):

You can use `legendItemClick` callback function, which is fired before `redraw` to add some custom flag on a chart, for example:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    redraw: function() {
      if (!this.isLegendItemClick) {
        console.log('chart redraw');
      } else {
        this.isLegendItemClick = false;
      }
    }
  }
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function() {
        this.chart.isLegendItemClick = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4930/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.events.legendItemClick

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw